Sci-fi/fantasy movie in which a man arrives on a planet to find two factions warring against each other
This is a sci-fi/fantasy movie (in color/year unknown) based on another planet.
A man arrives on the planet to find two factions warring against each other.  One male army versus another army of cyborg-type/elf-like women who recharge in some type of silo and rejoin the fight the next day.  Their battles are frequent, but, one side is never able to finish the other side off!  There were originally 7-11 other races on the planet, but only these two remain.
The astronaut who landed on the planet makes the acquaintance of with an elf-like individual who served as his de facto guide.  In the end, it turned out to be some kind of monster wearing the individual's skin.
The movie ended with some kind of mechanized giants rising from a red sea with cords plugged into them, linking them to the planet. Intent on destroying everyone, presumably.  Also, a picture of another planet slowly comes into the picture frame, clearly visible from this planet, that appears to be Earth!
The movie may have had parts of it as anime/animatronics.  I have not been able to find anyone who knows the title of this movie. The language used was English. I thought the name was "Dharm World", but I was wrong.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

I see that the account you used to post this question is unregistered. I don't know if you can still log in with it or not, but if you can't, I recommend opening a new account and then merging it with your previous one by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to post comments in this thread, which would be helpful, as identifying an unknown film can be much easier when you have some idea of when it was made, or at least when it was watched.

You mention animation mixed in - do you mean this is a live-action movie with animated parts that look like anime?

It seems you are using two different accounts to interact on this post. To regain access to your old account, merge your two accounts by following the procedure described in the Help Center.
